# Understanding a colorization algorithm using sparse matrix equation solvers

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, computer-vision

I am trying to understand a colorization algorithm (converting a gray scale image to color image), available in this paper Colorization using Optimization
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2896183_Colorization_using_Optimization

For a still image the algorithm inputs a gray-scale image $Y(x,y)$ and finds estimates of the chrominance channels, as in the YUV color space, $U(x,y)$ and $V(x,y)$, given the constraints that a user has assigned some subset of the $U(x,y)$ and $V(x,y)$ pixels as fixed.

Consider the $U$ channel. Then the goal is, for each pixel to minimize the difference between the color $U(x,y)$ at each pixel $(x,y)$ and a weighted average of the colors at neighboring pixels (implemented as a $3 \times 3$ window with appropriate truncation at the image borders) according to the cost function
$$C(U) = \sum \limits_{r}(U(r) - \sum \limits_{s \in N(r)} w_{rs} \cdot U(s))^2$$
where $r$ ranges overall the pixels in the image, and $N(r)$ is the neighbourhood of $r$. The cost function for $V$ is identical. The choice of affinity function $w_{rs}$ measuring how similar the gray-scale values of pixels $r,s$ is up to the implementation, where the authors choose $w_{rs} = \frac {d_{rs}} {\sum_{t \in N(r)} d_{rt}}$ for $s \in N(R)$ where $d_{rs} = e^ \frac{(Y(s)-Y(r))^2}{\sigma_r^2}$ and  $\sigma_r^2$ is the sample variance of intensity values in the window around $r$. For $s \notin N(R)$, $w_{rs}=0$.

The authors state:

> Since the cost functions are quadratic and the constraints are linear, this optimization problem yields a large, sparse system of linear equations, which may be solved using a number of standard methods.

So then, I believe for the images $U(x,y), V(x,y)$ that minimizing the cost function can be seen as solving for a vector $x$ that minimizes $||Ax-b||_2$ where $A = D-W$ and

- $W$ is the affinity matrix with $W_{rs} = w_{rs}$. Note $W$ is a sparse matrix.
- $D$ is a diagonal matrix with $1$'s on the main diagonal
- $x$ is the flattened image vector we are solving for

$W, D$ are of size $p \times p$ where $p$ is the number of pixels in the image. $x$ is a vector of size $p \times 1$, and $b$ is the same size as $x$.

My question is what is $b$? I am imagining $b$ enforces the constraints, but I am not sure how. The pixel constraint values are floats in the range $[0,1]$. I would be happy to clarify anything, any insights appreciated.

One possible solution for $b$ is that $b$ consists of a flattened image vector where if at a particular pixel the user has assigned a $U$ or $V$ channel value, then $b_{x,y}$ (before flattening) $=U(x,y)$ and $b_{x,y} = 0$ otherwise.

Comment: You've got more attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linear system that the authors refer to is [this system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming#Equality_constraints). So instead of minimizing $||Ax-b||$, you minimize $x^TQx + c^Tx$ (you can transfer one objective into the other so they are equivalent, but the latter has an easier expression for the derivative, and the matrix $Q$ is sparse while $A$ might not be sparse).

The dimension of $x$ is the number of pixels. Let me take your cost function and express it in $x$:
$$C(x) = \sum_i(x_i - \sum_j w_{ij} \cdot x_j)^2=\sum_i x_i^2 - \sum_i \sum_j w_{ij}x_i x_j$$
so indeed $Q=D-W$ and $c=0$. In fact, this is why in the paper they mention that the cost function is $x^T(D-W)x$ (in the right column next to formula (1)).

The constraints set the certain values of $x$, which can be modeled as $Ex=d$ where the number of rows in $E$ is the number of colored pixels and each row of $E$ has exactly one nonzero component. An alternative approach is to treat the fixed values as constants, meaning the dimensions of $Q$ and $c$ are a bit smaller, and you need $c \neq 0$ corresponding to the terms $\sum_i \sum_j w_{ij}x_i x_j$ where $x_i$ is fixed.

The only tricky part are the constraints $0 \leq x_i \leq 1$. One way of handling those is via an [interior point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior-point_method) method. It goes beyond the scope of this answer to fully explain the details, but in essence it adds the term $-\sum_i \mu \log(x_i)$ to the objective and gradually lets $\mu \downarrow 0$. For each $\mu$, you solve:
$$\begin{pmatrix}Q+S & E^T\\ E & O\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ \lambda \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}e \\ d\end{pmatrix}$$
where $S$ is a diagonal matrix and $S$ and $e$ are based on the current iterate of $x$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I have some followup questions. 1) How is the matrix $E$ determined? 
2) Can you give an idea of how $x^T Qx + c^Tx$ could be converted to optimizing $||Ax-b||$ ?

Comment: For instance my idea of what $E$ is would be a matrix of $n$ rows for $n$ constraints of size $n*p$, where in the $i'th$ row we would have the $i'th$ constraint pixel index (flattened to 1d) equal to $1$, with other values in the row equal to 0, and $d_i$ would be that corresponding pixel value.

Comment: 1) yes, that is how you would construct $E$, 2) minimizing $||Ax-b||$ is the same as minimizing $||Ax-b||^2$ (the value is different but the optimal $x$ is the same); $||Ax-b||^2=x^T(A^TAx)x -2b^TAx + b^Tb$. So you need $Q=A^TA$ and $c=2A^Tb$. Since $Q$ is positive semidefinite, it can be decomposed as $Q=UU^T$, then $A=U^T$. The system $c=2A^Tb$ does not always have a solution in $b$, so you cannot always do the conversion, unless $A$ has full rank.